# Why isn't GCC giving me an error

Tags: c++, gcc

GCC isn't giving me an error on an example I've made where I was hoping it would:

```
class CannotBeCopied {
public:
    CannotBeCopied(const CannotBeCopied&) = delete;
    CannotBeCopied& operator=(const CannotBeCopied&) =delete;
    CannotBeCopied() { }
    ~CannotBeCopied() { }
};

template<class T>
class FirstVector {
public:
    FirstVector() {
        size = 1;
        data = new T[size];
    }

    ~FirstVector() {
        delete[] data;
    }

    FirstVector(const FirstVector& source) {
        size = source.size;
        data = new T[size];
        for(int k=0;k!=size;k++) {
            data[k] = source.data[k]; //<--I EXPECT AN ERROR HERE
        }
    }
private:
    int size;
    T* data;
};
```

This error doesn't happen when the copy constructor isn't use (that is, it does happen when the copy constructor is used).

Because of the template I cannot simply move the copy-ctor into a code file and have that fail when it compiles.

How can I get this to fail?

This is not SFINAE, it should not be able to instantiate the template. If the copy-ctor was itself a template method (say by putting:

```
template<class U=T>
```

on the line above, then it'd be SFINAE.

I am using GCC 4.8.1, `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra` of course, and `-std=c++11`

I was hoping to get this to fail with:

```
int main() { 
    FirstVector<CannotBeCopied> whatever;
}
```

I know that GCC is just being lazy and not doing work it doesn't need to, but I do not like that if I were to explicitly instantiate this template in a code file, I'd get an error. Is there a way to get the error I want?

Comment: Have you tried invoking the copy constructor of `FirstVector<CannotBeCopied>`?

Comment: Oh yes @immibis - if you actually use it it does give the error. It should give the error whenever it is instantiated with a type with no copy-assignment.

Comment: The Java language specification calls Java pointers, pointers. Just show them that.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I thought I was gonna black out from rage at one point. Some people are just too far gone :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not just a matter of GCC being lazy; it is affirmatively prohibited from doing what you want it to do by the standard. [temp.inst]/p1, 2, 11:

> 1 Unless a class template specialization has been explicitly
>   instantiated (14.7.2) or explicitly specialized (14.7.3), the class
>   template specialization is implicitly instantiated when the
>   specialization is referenced in a context that requires a
>   completely-defined object type or when the completeness of the class
>   type affects the semantics of the program. [...] The implicit instantiation of
>   a class template specialization causes the implicit instantiation of
>   the declarations, but not of the definitions, default arguments, or
>   exception-specifications of the class member functions [...]
>
> 2  Unless a member of a class template or a member template has been
>   explicitly instantiated or explicitly specialized, the specialization
>   of the member is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is
>   referenced in a context that requires the member definition to exist.
>   [...]
>
> 11 An implementation shall not implicitly instantiate a function
>   template, a variable template, a member template, a non-virtual member
>   function, a member class, or a static data member of a class template
>   that does not require instantiation.

This allows you to have, e.g., `std::vector`s of move-only types. Their copy constructors will not compile, but as long as you don't use them, a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` is perfectly valid.

To force it to fail, you might use a `static_assert` inside `FirstVector`:

```
static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value, "T must be copy constructible");
```

Note, however, that this only checks that a declaration of the copy constructor is accessible and not deleted, not that the body of the copy constructor will compile, which means that it will falsely report that `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` is copy constructible.

Comment: Thank for! It's nice to have an answer that gets the question and answers it properly! Thank you ever so much.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't actually create an instance of your template, the copy constructor doesn't need to be called - the template code will not even be created for `CannotBeCopied`, if you don't use it. Invoke the copy constructor and you will get the error:

```
 FirstVector<CannotBeCopied> a;
 FirstVector<CannotBeCopied> b = a;
```

Edit: You may also use explicit instantiation of the template with all it's members by adding

```
template class FirstVector<CannotBeCopied>;
```

(§14.7.2 of language specification)

Comment: The first line of that should be sufficient to cause the error. If you EXPLICITLY instantiate the template you get the error (as if you put it in a code file)

Comment: Remember ` FirstVector<CannotBeCopied> a;` means "make the type `FirstVector<CannotBeCopied>` which cannot be done.

Comment: @I'mGettingThere: No, this can be done. It simply cannot be copied.

Comment: I can't delete this and re-post now, but this doesn't answer the question, stop upvoting!

Comment: The compiler is required to not implicitly instantiate members you don't use. Explicit instantiation of the class forces the instantiation of all members. This is all the correct behaviour.

Comment: @urzeit, it cannot be done. The type `FirstVector<CannotBeCopied>` isn't valid, it's not SFINAE because the copy constructor isn't a template.

Comment: @I'mGettingThere Good. Deleting and re-posting a question is a bad thing.

Comment: But the copy constructor of `FirstVector<CannotBeCopied>` is an instance of a template.

Comment: @AlanStokes is the compiler *allowed* to refuse to compile the code because of the copy constructor?

Comment: @AlanStokes I hate to be pedantic but is that actually what the standard says? That sounds like "an obvious optimisation" to save a lot of work. (also I'm not saying "generate code" for things that are not used, but check them)

Comment: @immibis when you see a q with a 2 line upvoted answer. there is no hope of another one.

Comment: @I'mGettingThere Yes, that is exactly what it says. If all members were implicitly instantiated lots of templates would break because of errors in unused members.

Comment: @urzeit it's not an instance of a template, the method itself is not templated, if you put (as I say in the Q) `template<class U=T>` before the copy-ctor then it's SFINAE

Comment: @immibis No, this code is well formed and can't be rejected.

Comment: @AlanStokes please make that into an answer. If true (which I'm checking) it deserves upvotes!

Comment: The answer says something I say in the question @AlanStokes

Comment: It *would* make sense if a template class's members were implicitly templates - consider `template<class T> class X {X() {T::doStuff();}}` - the constructor needs to be handled in the same way as if it was `class X {template<class T> X() {T::doStuff();}}`. (I don't know what the standard says either way)

Comment: @I'mGettingThere: Edited and added a paragraph about explicit instantiation

Comment: @I'mGettingThere I wouldn't say that urzeit didn't answer your question as written. Question: "Why don't I get an error?" - answer: "Because you don't instantiate the copy constructor". "Why don't I get an error?" is different from "Why is this class instantiation allowed despite the invalid copy constructor?". (And if you did repost this with the latter, I'd simplify it a bit - all your class needs is `template<class T> class X {X() {T::doStuff();}}` and then `X<int> x;`

Comment: the GCC compiler won't compile the things which wont be used, its the betterment that they have included. If u really want to get an error, just create an instance of the template or invoke the copy-ctor explicitly to get an error.

Comment: @urzeit that's in my answer also.

Comment: @immibis I say that in the question though! I recognise that using it gives me the error! I wanted to know why instantiation didn't give the error.

Answer (score 3):

Templates in C++ are only **materialized when they are used**.
Everything else would be too expensive.

As you may have heard, C++ templates are turing complete, so evaluating them can be is insanely expensive. IIRC there was an example somewhere of Fibonnaci<17>, which would have the compiler compute this number...

In particular this means the dead code will be eliminated, and the c++ compiler will only fail once you try to use the copy constructor.