# Visual Studio 2013 compiling successfully but with obvious error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2013. I have a rather odd problem. Normally people post about getting errors - I'm here posting about NOT getting errors.

I have written a custom Matrix class (for homework).
I have overriden the assignment operator as follows:

```
template<typename T>
Matrix<T>& Matrix<T>::operator=(const Matrix<T> &other) {
    if (this != &other) {
        if (this->mRows != other.mRows || this->nColumns != other.nColumns) {
            deleteMatrixArray();
            this->mRows = other.mRows;
            this->nColumns = other.nColumns;
            newMatrixArray();
        } // else reuse the existing array
        // copy contents
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < this->mRows; i++) {
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < this->nColumns; j++) {
                this->matrix[i][j] = other.matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

I recently changed the newMatrixArray() method to accept a bool parameter:

```
template<typename T>
void Matrix<T>::newMatrixArray(bool init) {
    this->matrix = new T*[this->mRows];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < this->mRows; i++) {
        if (init) {
            this->matrix[i] = new T[this->nColumns]();
        } else {
            this->matrix[i] = new T[this->nColumns];
        }
    }
}
```

However, Visual Studio still compiles successfully... UNLESS

```
#include "Matrix.h"

int main() {

    Matrix<int> matrix;

    Matrix<int> otherMatrix;
    otherMatrix = matrix;

    return 0;
}
```

I write some code that uses the overloaded assignment operator.
This is worrying me because now I don't know what else could be broken and Visual Studio isn't telling me!

What's going on with this?

More information:
As you can see, I am using templates. All the Matrix code is in the Matrix.h file - declaration followed by definition. This is required when using templates. The Matrix class is the only class I have right now in my project besides the main.cpp file. I have checked and made sure the declaration and definition match.

Credit: Praetorian
**Edit: (SOLUTION)**
You can use:

```
template class NameOfClass<NameOfType>;
```

to compile template classes against a certain type.

You can also use:

```
template ReturnType NameOfFunction(Args ... );
```

to compile outside-of-class methods with template arguments.

These should be placed in the global scope.

Comment: Please provide a complete but minimal example that readers can try out.

Comment: This is not incorrect behavior, member functions of class templates are only instantiated when you use them. If you want to force instantiation then explicitly instantiate `Matrix<int>` by adding the line `template class Matrix<int>;` at global scope in main.cpp. Then your code won't compile even without the `otherMatrix = matrix;` assignment.

Comment: Seems very similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28578061/why-isnt-gcc-giving-me-an-error), where basically it will only fail if you try and use it.

Comment: @Praetorian thanks! this revealed several errors in the class method implementations. i also overloaded the input/output operators but those are "outside" of the class and still aren't getting checked. :( I guess I'll have to manually use them to get them to compile.

Comment: @BradleyOdell You can do the same with function templates too, so something like `template std::ostream& operator<<<int>(std::ostream&, Matrix<int> const&);`

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> This is worrying me because now I don't know what else could be broken and Visual Studio isn't telling me!
>
> What's going on with this?

There is nothing wrong with what the compiler is doing. If a member function of a class template is not used, the function doesn't get instantiated. Some errors will be reported regardless of whether the function is instantiated or not, like mismatched parentheses, but other errors, like the one you mentioned won't be reported unless the function is instantiated.

Comment: @n.m., I took a quick glance at the section of the standard dealing with template instantiation but couldn't find anything that conclusively proves MSVC behavior is not standards compliant. I'll look more carefully.

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake. The bug I was thinking about is not relevant here. `newMatrixArray` is a dependent name so it shouldn't be checked. The bug is that MSVC doesn't do the checks even for non-dependent names.

Answer (score 0):

If something in a template isn't used, it won't be (fully) parsed either, and don't give out errors. 
It pretty much have to be this way, and this is not a VS bug, its conformant behaviour. 
Consider:

```
template<typename T>
class X
{
public:
    void work_always(const T&) {}
    void requires_copyable(T) {}
};
```

If you instance this on a type that is not copyable, it should still work, as long as you 
only use `work_always`

The standard library even uses this, for example vectors resize, that
require T to be
default constructible, but vector can still be used on types that aren't,
as long as you
dont call any methods requiring it.

This, of course, make template testing a bit hard, you have to make sure to use everything.

Answer (score 0):

The standard basically requires to perform most checks at declaration time. Only checks that cannot be so performed are postponed until instantiation time. The latter checks are those that involve *dependent names*. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name) for a detailed explanation.

Since `newMatrixArray` is dependent, it will not be checked until instantiation time. And if a member function is never used, it is not instantiated.

The reason for this rule is the fact that the meaning of a dependent name is not fully known until template parameters are known.

The problem with (at least some versions of) MSVC is that even non-dependent names are not checked until instantiation time. You can try to compile [this program](http://ideone.com/CIcRtL) to check if your compiler is affected. If it compiles, there is a bug.